# Voltage conversion between multiple orders

Tags: amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, operational-amplifier, voltage-amplification

I have this circuit in which I want to convert the input voltage of micro order to volt. The circuit image has been posted. I have figured out the bandpass filter ( basically everything after the big vertical dotted line). 
What I can't figure out is that the input offset voltage of AD620 is 30 micro volt. So it could create a problem. For that I have read that you need to use a capacitor in series with the feedback resistor but I don't know how to calculate the value.
If anyone has a better idea about this please do suggest!
Also another doubt I have is whether the comparator (TL084CN) after the instrumentation amplifier (AD620) will be able to shoot the milli order voltage to near Vcc value or at least bring it into order of volt?
The shape of the signal doesn't matter to me but only the frequency does . So I'm trying to shoot the voltage up before passing it into the bandpass filter.
If you have understood my goal and have better modifications to the circuit please let me know!

Datasheet used:
[AD620an](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/48091/AD/AD620AN.html)

[TL084CN](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/25392/STMICROELECTRONICS/TL084CN.html?)

Image of the circuit:
PS: The gain is 883 due to the 56 ohm resistor at instrumentation amplifier (not clearly seen in the image)
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qN0s.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qN0s.jpg)

Comment: Comparators tend to oscillate, if given a very small signal. Your instincts are good --- amplify a lot, then use the comparator. As I suggested to you in a prior answer, (1) use a low-noise opamp (and 50_ohm and 5Kohm resistors) in a non-inverting configuration. I suggest you (2) add another gain_of_100 opamp, perhaps DC_blocked on input; (3) a comparator with some hysteresis. Remember I described the random_noise_risk as severe.

Comment: Yes of course I remember..I am working on it actually..

Comment: That question will be removed.. It was posted by me but it is a lot unclear.. This one is better

Comment: @user183710 - "*That question will be removed*" You already have answers on that question, so I don't think that you *can* remove it, and so destroy the work by other people who wrote answers! Also, I see you are getting a reputation for not accepting *any* answers. Either you don't understand the process here, or you don't want to give credit for the best answer on each of your questions, or your questions are so vague that you aren't getting useful answers. But in all of those cases, there are things *you* can change :-) See [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Well so far every answer has been useful in one way or the other and also I can't upvote any answer cause I don't have enough reputation to do that

Comment: And I'm still new to this so I'm getting the hang of it..

Comment: @user183710 - Thanks for replying. I didn't say *upvote* (I know you can't do that yet), I said *accept*. That is the only action you can do, to mark a question as answered. If you don't accept an answer, then the website here may (depending on other parameters) continue to "nag" us in future to answer it, as there would be no indication that you have received enough of an answer. So please read the link I provided above, and note that "upvote" and "accept" actions are different things :-) I recommend you read the [tour] and [help], and I think you can visit [meta] to ask questions on this.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that.. Thanks..I will mark my previous questions as answered then

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.

Comment: I did edit it couple of times before but then I realized the info was still too narrow for me to get a solution so I decided to create a clean new slate ..won't happen again thanks..